# Access Django Form Method from Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I would like to add some logic to a form. And display data by category:

```
class CustomerType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
      return self.type

    def getCategory(self):
      return self.category
```

and would like to do something like this inside template:

```
  {% if field.getCategory == 0 %}
    {{ field }}
  {% else %}
   ...
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand your questions. what is the problem here?@DariusP

Comment: @EliakinCosta getCategory == 0 check does not work. Although I get no error..

Comment: @DariusP How you are passing the `field` to the template? Are you using django forms - ModelForms? Show us more detail (add view.py and forms.py)

Comment: @PedramParsian Nothing fancy, just a CreateView with a model and form_class